# Cypress and Typescript - your configFile is invalid: config.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cypress

I am trying to setup a custom take in Cypress and am running into a Cypress config error whenever I import a Typescript file into my `cypress.config.ts`. Here is my code:

**cypress.config.ts**

```
import 'dotenv-defaults/config';
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import db from './src/server/db/datasource';

const createDb = async () => {
  const server = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  try {
    db.setOptions({ url: server.getUri() });
    await db.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  return db;
};

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
          launchOptions.args.push('--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>');
          launchOptions.args.push('--disable-dev-shm-usage');
          launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
          launchOptions.args.push('--no-sandbox');

          return launchOptions;
        }
      });

      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message);
          return null;
        },
        /*  createDb() {
          return createDb();
        }, */
      });

      return config;
    },
    baseUrl: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`,
    video: false,
    screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
    modifyObstructiveCode: false, // Cypress utterly ruins Remix Context if this isn't disabled
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    experimentalSourceRewriting: true,
  },
  env: process.env,
});
```

The fourth line in the above file `import db from './src/server/db/datasource';` is what breaks the config and results in this error:

> Your configFile is invalid: /home/project/cypress.config.ts TypeError
> [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for
> /home/project/cypress.config.ts

I have Googled the error and it seems to be a known one with Cypress, I have tried all the suggestions including upgrading Cypress to the latest version (`^10.11.0`) but none have helped.

I have tried planing around with my tsconfig.json but have not been able to make a difference. Here is that file:

```
{
  "include": ["./*", "src", "test", "types", "scripts"],
  "exclude": ["cypress" /* "./cypress.config.ts" */],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2019",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@test": ["./test"],
      "@test/*": ["./test/*"]
    }
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
}
```

The command I am running to launch cypress is just `npx cypress open`. Would love some help as it's unclear what is causing this issue!

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using? I ended up having to downgrade to TypeScript 5.2 for the error to go away in my case

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it with Below Method

1. Delete node_module Folder
2. Delete package-lock.json·
3. Run npm cache clean --force  Command Twice
4. Run npm i·

Comment: What is your reasoning for running `npm cache clean` twice? Does it not work the first time?